# How to show Snackbar at top of the screen

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar

**As the Android documentation says**

> Snackbars provide lightweight feedback about an operation. They show a brief message at the bottom of the screen on mobile and lower left on larger devices.

Is there any alternative by which we can show `snackbars` at top of the screen instead of the bottom?

Right now I am doing something like this which shows a `snackbar` at the bottom of the screen.

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Hello this is a snackbar!!!", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Undo", mOnClickListener)
.setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
.show();
```

Answer (score 188):

It is possible to make the snackbar appear on top of the screen using this:

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, str, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snack.show();
```

From the OP:

> I had to change the first line:
>
> ```
> Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
> ```

Comment: The animation on the `SnackBar` slides up which makes this look horrible. I haven't tried it yet, but here is a library project that shows a `SnackBar` with the correct animations: https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar

I feel like I'm in ##java on IRC.

Comment: If you are using a Coordinator layout somewhere above in the hierarchy, this code crashes with a *ClassCastException, CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to FrameLayout$LayoutParams*. *Support v24* only uses a FrameLayout as snackbar container if it doesn't find a *CoordinatorLayout* ancestor or if its id is *android.R.id.content*. See *SnackBar.findSuitableParent* for implementation details. 

You can hack the system by setting your FrameLayout's id to *android.R.id.content*, but that may stop working in the future.

Comment: It's quite ugly solution. If you are using any layout (except FrameLayout) it will crash.

Comment: I am using Relative Layout and it is working, but animation is bad

Comment: This works regardless of the parent layout whether it's a FrameLayout, LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout, etc.

Comment: How to do this with ConstraintLayout?

Comment: I believe this answer is not valid anymore target android 9.0:  `View view = snack.getView();`  should be replaced by `View view = snack.View;` I don't know about  the rest. Any chance you revive your answer for 2020?

Comment: Really bad solutions. It looks horrible. You see the animation

Answer (score 56):

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout=(CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snackbar.getView();
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params=(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: This one is working  . Adarsh Yadav's solution is down casting CoordinatorLayout to FrameLayout there  may be chance to crash the app

Comment: Be safe, Using `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` may result in crash. `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` works fine.

Comment: And they scored a very rare badge for this answer! One of three answers total. Come back Vijayan, we miss you.

Comment: How can I use this approach when the class where I create the snackbar is not a Fragment or a View class but just a normal Java class and thus I can't use `findViewById`?

Comment: @VanessaF Not easily. We created a base class for our activities which registers itself as an observer to an event hub, then we publish events to the event hub from "normal" classes to signal the activity that it needs to display the snackbar.

Answer (score 30):

## Kotlin-

```
    val snackBarView = Snackbar.make(view, "SnackBar Message" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    val view = snackBarView.view
    val params = view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
    view.layoutParams = params
    view.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.custom_drawable) // for custom background
    snackBarView.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
    snackBarView.show()
```

below line will resolve the animation issue.

```
snackBarView.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
```

Alternate solution-
`snackBarView.anchorView = mention viewId above whom you want to show SnackBar`

Comment: It's worth noting that 
`snackBarView.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE` is not available in older versions of the material library. Not sure which version this animation mode first appears in, but it's definitely in material:1.4.0

Comment: Unfortunately material:1.0.0 does not have that property

Answer (score 29):

You can do the following to position a SnackBar anywhere inside a layout (**This method has No Animation Issues**)

1) According to:

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make(android.view.View, java.lang.CharSequence, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#make(android.view.View,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int))

> Snackbar make (View view, 
>                   CharSequence text, 
>                   int duration)
>
> Make a Snackbar to display a message  **Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from
>   the value given to view. Snackbar will walk up the view tree trying to
>   find a suitable parent, which is defined as a CoordinatorLayout or the
>   window decor's content view, whichever comes first.**

So, one can position a snackBar anywhere inside a layout simply by adding a Coordinator Layout in the desired location and using that Coordinator Layout as the view argument inside Snackbar.make method above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/rl"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Coordinator Layout used to position the SnackBar -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cl"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- add your layout here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) The Coordinator Layout used to display the SnackBar should be on top of all other views (highest elevation). In order to do that, one might either call `bringToFront()` on the coordinator layout or elevate the coordinator layout (add
`android:elevation="10dp"` for example)

3) At this point the snackBar will show up in the desired location, but the snackBar is displayed with a bottom to top animation (default behavior). In order to achieve a top to bottom animation, you can do the following:

- **Rotate Coordinator layout used inside Snackbar.make method by 180 degrees**

4) After step 3, the snackBar will be displayed with a top to bottom animation, but the message and action text are rotated and the gravity is reversed, so as a final step, I did the following:

- **Got SnackBar View, found the LinearLayout holding the TextView responsible about displaying the message and the TextView responsible about the action, and rotated the parent LinearLayout by 180 degress**

5) Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private RelativeLayout rl;
private CoordinatorLayout cl;
private CoordinatorLayout cl1;
private CoordinatorLayout cl2;
private CoordinatorLayout cl3;
private CoordinatorLayout cl4;
private Snackbar snackbar_updated;
private Snackbar snackbar_updated1;
private Snackbar snackbar_updated2;
private Snackbar snackbar_updated3;
private Snackbar snackbar_updated4;
private Snackbar snackbar_ordinary;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    cl = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl);
    cl1 = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl1);
    cl2 = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl2);
    cl3 = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl3);
    cl4 = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl4);
    cl.bringToFront();
    cl1.bringToFront();
    cl2.bringToFront();
    cl3.bringToFront();
    cl4.bringToFront();

    snackbar_updated = Snackbar.make(cl, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar_updated.setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    /** Snackbar message and action TextViews are placed inside a LinearLayout
     */
    final Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarLayout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar_updated.getView();
    for (int i = 0; i < snackBarLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View parent = snackBarLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (parent instanceof LinearLayout) {
            ((LinearLayout) parent).setRotation(180);
            break;
        }
    }

    snackbar_updated1 = Snackbar.make(cl1, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar_updated1.setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    /** Snackbar message and action TextViews are placed inside a LinearLayout
     */
    final Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarLayout1 = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar_updated1.getView();
    for (int i = 0; i < snackBarLayout1.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View parent = snackBarLayout1.getChildAt(i);
        if (parent instanceof LinearLayout) {
            ((LinearLayout) parent).setRotation(180);
            break;
        }
    }

    snackbar_updated2 = Snackbar.make(cl2, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar_updated2.setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    snackbar_updated3 = Snackbar.make(cl3, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar_updated3.setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    /** Snackbar message and action TextViews are placed inside a LinearLayout
     */
    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackBarLayout3 = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar_updated3.getView();
    for (int i = 0; i < snackBarLayout3.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View parent = snackBarLayout3.getChildAt(i);
        if (parent instanceof LinearLayout) {
            ((LinearLayout) parent).setRotation(180);
            break;
        }
    }

    snackbar_updated4 = Snackbar.make(cl4, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar_updated4.setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    snackbar_ordinary = Snackbar.make(rl, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar_ordinary.setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    rl.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            snackbar_updated.show();
            rl.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    snackbar_updated1.show();
                    rl.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            snackbar_updated2.show();
                            rl.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    snackbar_updated3.show();
                                    rl.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            snackbar_updated4.show();
                                            rl.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    snackbar_ordinary.show();
                                                }
                                            }, 2000);
                                        }
                                    }, 2000);
                                }
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });

}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/rl"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Coordinator Layout used to position the SnackBar -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cl"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="#333"
        app:itemTextColor="#333"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_top"
            android:text="Layout Top"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        </TextView>

        <!-- Coordinator Layout used to position the SnackBar -->

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cl1"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_top"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


        <!-- Coordinator Layout used to position the SnackBar -->

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cl2"
            android:paddingBottom="75dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <!-- Coordinator Layout used to position the SnackBar -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_center"
            android:text="Center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        </TextView>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cl3"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:paddingBottom="75dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_bottom"
            android:text="Layout Bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        </TextView>

        <!-- Coordinator Layout used to position the SnackBar -->

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cl4"
            android:layout_above="@id/tv_bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

6) Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Very sneaky. Works perfectly.

Comment: Love it, combined with @Deepak's answer you can avoid the rotation part of this answer by simply using a fade animation on the snackbar (instead of slide)

Comment: try snackbarView.setRotation(180);

Comment: For a version with more brevity, set `android:rotation="180"` in the `CoordinatorLayout` xml definition, then use `snackbar.getView().rotation = 180.0f` (kotlin).   This makes it slide upward with the content the right way around.

Comment: Cool stuff one minor issue though, you then need to swipe left to dismiss the rotated snackbar instead of the usual swipe right. That and the solution description could be a lot more concise.

Comment: good trick! It really saves my day

Answer (score 17):

Combined solution from the above ones:

```
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams();
if (params instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
    ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) params).gravity = Gravity.TOP;
} else {
    ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) params).gravity = Gravity.TOP;
}
snackbar.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

Still suffers from the improper animation.

Comment: Pretty silly. Just use `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();' which is the parent for most layouts.

Comment: yup. toast now just fills screen. still appears bottom up. not top down

Answer (score 9):

This makes the Snackbar appears on Top without the strange slide in transition.

Best simple solution in Kotlin:

```
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, string, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    val layoutParams = LayoutParams(snackbar.view.layoutParams)

    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP
    snackbar.view.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0)
    snackbar.view.layoutParams = layoutParams
    snackbar.animationMode = BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE
    snackbar.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

### Idiomatic Kotlin version

```
snackbar.view.layoutParams = (snackbar.view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
  gravity = Gravity.TOP
}
```

### Kotlin extension

```
/** Kotlin extension that adds this snackbar at the top of the screen. */
fun Snackbar.gravityTop() {
  this.view.layoutParams = (this.view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
    gravity = Gravity.TOP
  }
}
```

Then just call:

```
snackbar.gravityTop()
```

Comment: This crashes my friend

Answer (score 3):

Before displaying the Snackbar, please add the following code

```
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();

FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) snackbarView.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
snackbarView.setLayoutParams(params);
snackbarView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(host, R.anim.slide_in_snack_bar));
```

And when dismiss()

```
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
  
snackbarView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_snackbar.getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_snack_bar));
snackbar.dismiss()
```

slide_in_snack_bar.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

slide_out_snack_bar.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
```

Comment: Works! Easy solution.

Comment: Does only work with Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE though

Comment: what is "host" ?

Comment: It is Context. Sorry for this "host" - it can confuse anyone.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `Constraintlayoutas` as the root parent, with the help of Guidelines and `CoordinatorLayout`  you can try this:

changing the value of:  layout_constraintGuide_end="Your bottom margin value" inside Guideline as below example.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline3" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="150dp" />
```

in the activty you can pass CoordinatorLayout  as the view for the snackbar

```
mSnackBar = Snackbar.make(
            coordinator,
            getString(R.string.no_internet_connection),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
        )
        mSnackBar.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

why not anchor it to some other view say you have other views in layout just anchor the snackbar to some view so that it displays there for example:

```
<LinearLayout>
......<Button>

<LinearLayout>
<TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

in code:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,message, snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAnchorView(R.id.reg_button);
```

R.id.reg_button is the button in the layout it can be anywhere snackbar will show up right there
No need to use any frame etc app will function as expected will not crash

Answer (score 0):

2 years later, here's my solution..

Setting the Top and Bottom Margin changes the effect result,... I have tried to add as much customization options as i could, Overriding the animation is another option not written here.

Thanks to everyone's answers on several questions...

```
{
    // usage for setSnackBar
    int view = R.id.toolbar;
    String snackMessage = "";
    boolean useAction = false;
    Runnable ifUseActionRunnable = null;
    String actionText = "";
    int leftMargin = 0;
    int topMargin = 0;
    int rightMargin = 0;
    int bottomMargin = 0;
    int backgroundColour = Color.BLACK;
    int textColor = Color.WHITE;
    int duration = Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG;
    setSnackBar(view, snackMessage, useAction, ifUseActionRunnable, actionText, leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin, backgroundColour, textColor, duration);

}

Snackbar snb;
public void setSnackBar(int targetView, String snackMessage, boolean useAction, final Runnable ifUseActionRunnable, String actionText , int leftMargin, int topMargin, int rightMargin, int bottomMargin, int backgroundColour, int textColor, int duration)
{
    snb = Snackbar.make(findViewById(targetView), snackMessage, duration);
    View view = snb.getView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColour);
    snb.setActionTextColor(textColor);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
    params.gravity =  Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
    params.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    if (useAction)
    {
        snb.setAction(actionText, new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    ifUseActionRunnable.run();

                }
            });
    }
    if (snb.isShown())
    {
        snb.dismiss();
        snb.show();
    }
    else
    {
        snb.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to show Snackbar at top of the screen (kotlin)

```
// Custom snackbar : banner model
            val customSnackBar   = Snackbar.make(snackbar_id, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)

            val view = customSnackBar.view
            val params = view.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
            view.layoutParams = params

            val layout           = customSnackBar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
            val customSnackView  = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snackbar_banner, null)

            val actionButton1   = customSnackView.findViewById(R.id.action_button_1) as MaterialButton
            actionButton1.setOnClickListener {
                customSnackBar.dismiss()
            }
            val actionButton   = customSnackView.findViewById(R.id.action_button_2) as MaterialButton
            actionButton.setOnClickListener {
                customSnackBar.dismiss()
            }

            // We can also customize the above controls
            layout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
            layout.addView(customSnackView, 0)


            customSnackBar.show()
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
   >

    <TextView
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/snackbar_banner_message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/action_button_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:text="Close"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
           />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/action_button_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:text="Fix it"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
           />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the approaches discussed above i have made a simple project to make a snackbar appear from top and it has no weird animations. Using the LayoutParams from the snackbar and using a custom layout to achieve this.
Please refer to my github repo:
[Here -> TopSnackbar](https://github.com/khizzar/TopSnackBar)