# snackbar not appearing on top of fragment layout/recyclerview within viewpager

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am trying to get snackbar below 3 tabs .I have inflated a fragment and implemented coordinator layout within that.I am unable to display snackbar on top below tabs.And getView() displays snackbar at the bottom above floating button and this code [How to show Snackbar at top of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746300/how-to-show-snackbar-at-top-of-the-screen?rq=1) displays snackbar right on top which I don't want. How to make snackbar display below tabs in fragment?

Code:

```
 Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout_snackbar, “Snackbar”, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(“click”, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "button clicked");
                            }
                        });

                snackbar.show();
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_snackbar”
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your SwipeRefreshLayout inside the CoordinatorLayout, like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout_snackbar”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your current layout, the SwipeRefreshLayout is drawn over the CoordinatorLayout, which has height 0, because it has no children and height set as wrap_content.

Comment: how can I set it on top.It currently does not even display until I scroll down.Its kind of hidden.

Comment: You have to put the CoordinatorLayout in the Activity layout, so that the whole fragment is contained in the CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: CAn you please explain by code ? I tried it and it still shows below the layout.