# change position of the snakBar to top programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want when **snakbar** is appeared, to be displayed to top. for this I write this command:

```
Snackbar mSnak = Snackbar.make(viewHolder.messageBlock, str, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
TextView mTextView = mSnak.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
mTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);                                  
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)mSnak.getView().getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
mSnak.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
mSnak.show();
```

But it does not work?? and still is appeared at bottom.How does one change the **SnackBar 's initial alignment**??

Comment: why downvote!!!!!!?

Comment: any of the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746300/how-to-show-snackbar-at-top-of-the-screen did not get answer 's mark.

Answer (score -1):

make the snackbar appear on top of the screen using this:

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

View view = snack.getView();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snack.show();
```

Comment: why copy paste from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746370/4448617

Comment: dude what is the deference between your answer and my question?