# How to show a Flutter SnackBar widget at the top?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

Is there a way to show a [Flutter Snackbar](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars) at the top of the screen rather than at the bottom?

According to the docs you can set `behaviour: SnackBarBehavior.floating` and that raises slightly the snackbar and makes it look a bit like a popup, but it still doesn't provide an option to explicitly set the positioning at the top, for example, right below the action bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this plugin: flushbar

Flushbar(
flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
)

Comment: I've seen the `flushbar` plugin before posting the question; would prefer to stick to the standard ootb widgets.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is described here. [Flutter Snakbar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html)- A lightweight message with an optional action which briefly displays at the **bottom** of the screen.

and I found an alternative [flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar). using flushbar you can change position TOP/BOTTOM.

```
  Flushbar(
    flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.TOP,
    message:
        "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
  )..show(context);
```

Comment: Flushbar is a 3rd party library. I was looking at ways to do it with the ootb SnackBar, possibly by passing a different `context` object similar to how Snackbar works in android where the Snackbar is anchored to a specific widget.

Comment: @ccpizza I understand what you are looking in to. According to Material design, Snackbars used to provide brief messages about app processes at the bottom of the screen. have a look - [Snackbar](https://material.io/components/snackbars)

Comment: yes, i know, yet the android native snackbar can be tweaked to appear on top, eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746370/191246 — I was assuming something similar might be possible with flutter.

Comment: The Flushbar is labeled discontinued. If you want another similar package, use this package [another_flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar)