# How to show a Snackbar in Android on the top when using ConstraintLayout in a nice way

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout, android-snackbar

I am using ConstraintLayout in Android and I would like to display a Snackbar message at the top of the screen. I found this question on Stackoverflow: [How to show Snackbar at top of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746300/how-to-show-snackbar-at-top-of-the-screen)

The answer with the most likes is quite bad as it looks horrible because you can see the Snackbar beeing animated to the top:

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, str, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snack.show();
```

The second answer assumes that you are using a CorrdinatorLayout which I don't do

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout=(CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snackbar.getView();
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params=(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snackbar.show();
```

Do you know how I can display the SnackBar in a ConstraintLayout on top in a nice way (meaning that it will just pop up at the top of the screen without being animated to the top)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the first piece of code and do the following:

Add this line to resolve the animation issue :

```
snackbar.setAnimationMode(BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_FADE);
```

If this doesn't works try this:

```
snackbar.setAnchorView(*mention viewId above whom you want to show SnackBar*)
```

Comment: Thanks Arsh for your answer. The first line helped to remove the animation. I accepted and upvoted your answer. Maybe one follow-up question regarding Snackbars. Do you know if it's possible to display the Snackbar longer? I already use `Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG` but this is not long enough for me. Any idea?

Comment: try ```Snackbar.make(parentLayout, str, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setDuration(*your duration*);```

Comment: I appreciate your further answer Arsh. Great help.